# When I access static const member variable in two different cpps, got "multiple definition"

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I have a non-template class String(string.h):

```
class String {
 public:
  static const unsigned int npos;
  ...
};
```

And I initialize it in different cpp file(string.cpp):

```
const unsigned int String::npos = static_cast<unsigned int>(-1);
```

When I use the String in different cpps, I got multiple definition error.

I have read the code of std::string in STL. The basic_string likes that:

```
template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits, typename _Alloc>
class basic_string
{
public:
  ...
  ///  Value returned by various member functions when they fail.
  static const size_type    npos = static_cast<size_type>(-1);
  ...
```

And the implementation of some functions are in the basic_string.tcc, and the declaration of 'npos' also in this file:

```
namespace std _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default)
{
_GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION

#if _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI

  template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits, typename _Alloc>
    const typename basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type
    basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::npos;
  ...
```

But when I use std::string, it will not cause any errors.

So why STL has no errors, but I do wrong there. How to correct it? Thank you.

Update:

Actually I use gtest to test my class:

I change the implementation string.cpp file to string-impl.h file, but it doesn't work.

string-indexof-char-test.cc:

```
#include "string-def.h"
#include "string-impl.h"

#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(IndexOfTest, CharTest) {
  String str = "123456";
  EXPECT_EQ(str.IndexOf('0'), String::npos);
}
```

string-indexof-sequence-test.cc:

```
#include "string-def.h"
#include "string-impl.h"

#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(IndexOfTest, CharTest) {
  String str = "123456";
  EXPECT_EQ(str.IndexOf("000"), String::npos);
}
```

When I simply run all my tests (other tests are irrelevant), the error occurs.

```
CMakeFiles\tests.dir/objects.a(string-indexof-char-test.cc.obj):string-indexof-char-test.cc:(.rdata+0x640): 
multiple definition of `citron::String::npos'
CMakeFiles\tests.dir/objects.a(string-indexof-sequence-test.cc.obj):string-indexof-sequence-test.cc:(.rdata+0x230): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Please include the error message.

Comment: Can you set up a [MCVE] that reproduces your problem please? Do you have proper header include guards?

Comment: You don't need/should include your implementation file in the test code. Just link it to the test runner.

Comment: @user0042 not if that's template implementation. But OP says that the variable is defined in .cpp file..

Comment: @Swift If it's a template definition, shouldn't the template defintion code already be include by the header?

Comment: @user0042 I wouldn't bet on that with homemade header. Though what if that file was included from that header? :P

Comment: Make sure that line `const unsigned int String::npos = -1;` wasn't included into both compile modules and thus into both  .o files. If you use C++17 compiler you may omit that fully, by initializing  it inside class,  also make that `constexpr` instead of `const`

Answer (score 1):

Probably something is wrong with header include guard of string.h.
You can try using `#pragma once` to solve the problem.

```
#pragma once

class String {
 public:
  static const unsigned int npos;
  ...
};
```